# Change Custom Views drawing when button is clicked in Swift OS X app

Tags: macos, swift, drawing, nsview

So in my Swift OS X app I have one custom view and one button. When I start my app, my view shows a red oval and I need to change that drawing to `drawRectangle()`-method when i click my button.

My custom view's class `MyView` looks like following:

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit

class MyView: NSView {

    var isTrue = true

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
        if isTrue {
            DrawingMethods.drawOval()
        } else {
            DrawingMethods.drawRectangle()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        isTrue = false
        // Now I need to update the view, so it draws rectangle isntead of oval. How I do that?

    }
}
```

And I have my `DrawingMethods` class:

```
import Cocoa

public class DrawingMethods: NSObject {

    public class func drawOval() {

        let color = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        let ovalPath = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: NSMakeRect(64, 54, 50, 45))
        color.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()
    }

    public class func drawRectangle() {

        let color = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        let rectanglePath = NSBezierPath(rect: NSMakeRect(136, 12, 34, 34))
        color.setFill()
        rectanglePath.fill()
    }
}
```

So how can i get my custom views draw rectangle instead of oval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setNeedsDisplayInRect()` on the view after setting `isTrue = false`.  This will notify the view that it needs to redraw and `drawRect` will be called again.

Your `buttonPressed` function should be defined in the `ViewController` that contains the custom view

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet customView: MyView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        customView.isTrue = false
        customView.setNeedsDisplayInRect(customView.bounds)
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can just set the `needsDisplay` property of the view to `true` to redraw the entire view:

```
customView.needsDisplay = true
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm very noob at programming and poor in english, I don't know what flag means in this context. I only know "capture the 'flag'" :)

So should I call that function in my 'buttonPressed' function? Can you please show in code how do you do that?

Comment: So like this?
    setNeedsDisplayInRect(<#invalidRect: NSRect#>)
What i'm supposed to put in parenthesis?